# Programatically setting route params in React-Router V4 ends up in 'Page not found'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to set route param programmatically from a function in a component, like this :

```js
this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/SupportSectionReports',
    search: '?reportType=0'
    });
```

And here is how I handled the route in my router file (say router.js) :

```jsx
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />        
    <Route  path="/home" component={Home} />   
    <Route path="/SupportSectionReports/:reportType" component={Home} /> 
</Switch>
```

This is how I added the route in my router file,
 so basically, I expect it to load my Home component when the path is '/SupportSectionReports?reportType=0', but what I get instead is this message that you can see it from the picture below(and the Home component doesn't load eventually):

[page not found message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rs6u.png)

What is it that I'm missing? Am I setting the route param in a wrong way? What would be the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have route mismatch because your rule contains path variable, but you provide only search query:

```
<Route path="/SupportSectionReports/:reportType" component={Home} />
```

#### 1) You need to provide path variable to router:

```
this.props.history.push({
    pathname: `/SupportSectionReports/0`
});
```

#### 2) Or just remove path variable from your route:

```
<Route path="/SupportSectionReports" component={Home} />
```

And in Home component you can grab query params from router search.

Or provide path variable

Comment: tnx a bunch, can you provide me with an example on how to grab that query param in Home component(say I removed the path from my route and provided the search query)? I was thinking about `this.props.match.params` but that is not the case, right?

Comment: @ForoughFallah try to console `this.props.location.search`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the column notation in route path, then you should just pass the value of that named parameter when pushing:

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/SupportSectionReports/0'
});
```